# normal distribution sample mean

Tags: normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Kofi owns a cinema. He wishes to increase attendances and so considers offering customers unlimited amounts of free popcorn and soft drinks.

He estimates that the likely increase in attendances would result in his business being more profitable, provided that the mean value of the free items consumed by each customer was less than £1.50.

Before deciding whether to proceed, Kofi offers 60 customers entering the cinema free popcorn and soft drinks. The value of the items consumed by each of these customers has a mean of £1.33 and a standard deviation of £0.45. These customers may be regarded as a random sample of all his current customers.

Examine whether the mean value of free popcorn and soft drinks that would be consumed by his current customers is less than £1.50. Use the 5% significance level:

Unsure what to do here. I think X is normally distributed by (1.5, 0.45^2), but am I unsure? Is the normal distribution instead (1.3, (0.45^2)/60)? And if so how do I do this hypothesis test? For P(X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view it is a hypothesis test. I would recommend a one sided test. The sample mean can be approximately considered as normal distributed since the sample size is larger than $30$ (Thumb rule). The sample mean is approximately distributed as $\overline X\sim \mathcal N\left(1.5, \frac{0.45^2}{60}\right)$.

The hypotheses are

$H_0: \mu\geq 1.5$

$H_1: \mu< 1.5$

The critical value is $\Phi^{-1}(0.05)=-1.645=z_{0.05}$. And the standardized empirical value is $z=\frac{1.33-1.5}{\frac{0.45}{\sqrt{60}}}=-2.93$

Since $z<z_{0.05}$ we reject the null hypothesis

Comment: When you're doing hypothesis tests you usually P(observed value or fewer) as the p-value, what is the observed value in this case, 1.5 or 1.3?

Comment: You can use the z-score as well. See [here](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/z-score/)

Comment: Why is the critical value -1.645? When I put it in the calculator Inverse normal area = 0.05, s.d. = 0.45/root(60) and   μ = 1.33 I don't anywhere near -1.645

Comment: @WaveX I´ve made an edit. Thanks.

Comment: @SamConnell "When I put it in the calculator Inverse normal area = 0.05" That is what we do and we get $-1.645$. This is a standardized threshold. To compare it with the empirical data we have to standardize the empirical value.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense

Comment: @SamConnell If it it clear now than please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Can you do the question by using a 90% confidence interval?

Comment: @SamConnell In this case it is even more clearer since $\Phi^{-1}(0.1)=-1.282$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the random variable for the value of the items consumed.

Note that $x$ is **not necessarily** normally distributed (and most likely it probably is not), but it has a mean of $\mu$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma$.

However, by the Central Limit Theorem, $\bar{x}$ is **approximately normally distributed** with a mean of $\mu$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma / \sqrt{60}$

You can test the hypothesis using $\sigma \approx 0.45$ since the sample size is sufficiently large.

Comment: But what is μ in this instance and what value is x for P(X<x)?

Comment: $\mu$ is unknown; hence why you are doing a hypothesis test in the first place. And what you should look at is $P(\bar{x} \lt 1.33)$ based on the assumption that $\mu = 1.5$. If this p-value is sufficiently small (less than $0.05$) you would reject the hypothesis that $\mu = 1.5$

Comment: Can you do the question with a 90% confidence interval?